# Counting unique rows with nested select - help me optimise

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, group-by, query-optimization

I have this weird query

```
SELECT t.something_id, t.platform, t.country, SUM(t.amnt) AS amountz
FROM ( SELECT something_id, platform, country, 1 AS amnt
       FROM log_table
       WHERE target_date = '2018-02-09'
       GROUP BY (unique_key) ) t
GROUP BY t.something_id, t.country, t.platform
```

The log table has unique players and a counter, where if the player has multiple sessions - it's updated. It's working based on an unique index where every day there a separate row for a unique user inserted so we could analyze the data.At this point the table grew quite a bit, and running this query to count yesterdays unique users is quite a difficult task.

Running a explain extended query gives me this result:

```
| id    | select_type   | table         | type      | possible_keys     | key               | key_len   | ref           | rows          | filtered  | Extra         |           |           |           |
|----   |-------------  |-----------    |-------    |---------------    |------------------ |---------  |-----------    |-----------    |---------- |------------   |--------   |---------- |-------    |
| 1     | PRIMARY       | <derived2>    | ALL       | NULL              | NULL              | NULL      | NULL           | 114441375    | 100.00    | Using         | temporary;| Using     | filesort  |
| 2     | DERIVED       | log_table     | index     | NULL              | idx_multi_column  | 944       | NULL          | 114441375     | 100.00    | Using         | where;    |Using      | index     |
```

my structure:

```
| Name          | Type          |
|-------------  |-------------- |
| stat_id       | int(8)        |
| metric        | tinyint(1)    |
| platform      | tinyint(1)    |
| something_id  | varchar(128)  |
| target_date   | date          |
| country       | varchar(2)    |
| amount        | int(100)      |
| unique_key    | varchar(180)  |
| created       | timestamp     |
| modified      | timestamp     |
```

index that I'm using:
`idx_multi_column` = `unique_key,target_date,country,platform,something_id`

I'm aware that the first elect that nests the second select uses temporary storage and because of the amount of rows that slows things a lot. Any way to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your query could be simplified using aggregate function COUNT(DISTINCT...) :

```
SELECT 
   something_id, 
    platform, 
    country, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT unique_key) AS amountz
FROM log_table
WHERE target_date = '2018-02-09'
GROUP BY something_id, country, platform
```

If there are no duplicate unique_id for a given something_id/platform/country, then you may remove the DISTINCT keyword ; this should increase performance.

Comment: I've edited your query, this seems to use filesort when running with explain extended - is there a way to prevent this from happening? filesort is pretty slow right?

Comment: group by implies `ORDER BY`. You can `ORDER BY NULL` to avoid the sort.  As an index `target_date, something_id, country, platform, unique_key` to help this query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is the query you want as (GMB points out):

```
SELECT something_id, platform, country, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT unique_key) AS amountz
FROM log_table
WHERE target_date = '2018-02-09'
GROUP BY something_id, country, platform
```

For performance, try an index on `log_table(target_date, something_id, country, platform, unique_key)`.

Comment: this is basically a copy of @GMB 's answer, i accepted his version because he was the first to answer. Thanks.

Comment: @PaaPs . . . The point was to explain what indexes work best for the query.